# How can I convert a value to a CGPoint?

Tags: iphone, cgpoint

I´ve got a problem with my Xcode-Project and hope you can help me!
I just began coding, so my problem should be very easy to solve.

I wanna make a Pong Game with two paddles and a ball. I have got a value, which is between 0 and 1. If the value is high the paddle should also go up. The paddle position can be changed with "CGPoint", but how can I convert my value to a point?

Please help me.
Thanks and greets from Germany :)

Comment: What you are asking for is a way to convert paddle position in screen coordinates to draw them? It's not so clear what you're searching for.

Comment: Guten tag, CGPoint pp = CGPointMake( value * 480.0, 500 ); .. alles klar!  ODER .. yourImageView.center = CGPointMake( value * 480.0, 500 );

Answer (score 6):

`CGPoint` is a 2-dimensional point.

```
struct CGPoint {
  CGFloat x;
  CGFloat y;
};
typedef struct CGPoint CGPoint;
```

You can create a `CGPoint` with `CGPointMake(x,y)`.
When your value is between 0 and 1 you may want to scale either x or y by multiplying with a constant factor.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! So you mean I should multiply my value with e.g. 480 (landscape) and make a CGPoint with it. So how can I multiply the value? Is there a special function?

Answer (score 0):

I have a better idea for the paddle controll:

You can use the users touch imput to controll the paddle:

```
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint pointToMove = [touch locationInView:self.view];

    yourImage.center = CGPointMake(yourImage.center.x, pointToMove.y);

}
```

When the user touches the screen, the paddle moves to the .y position of the touch but stays on its defaulf x cordinates!

That way, the controlls would be more fluid. Just try it out!

Viel Spass beim programmieren :D

Answer (score 0):

This is exact code from my app to do this job

```
for (id obj in points) {
[self moveToPoint:[((NSValue*) obj) CGPointValue]];
```